# Bootstrap carousel left right nav issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I copied the following [carousel](http://www.bootply.com/81478) for bootstrap 3.  When first load it, it looks good.

[image]

But when I click on either the left or right navigation the bottom expands (I circled it in red):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .carousel-control {
            padding-top: 10%;
            width: 5%;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider</h1>

            <div class="well">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/row-->
                        </div>
                        <!--/item-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/row-->
                        </div>
                        <!--/item-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/row-->
                        </div>
                        <!--/item-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&#60;</a>

                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&#62;</a>
                </div>
                <!--/myCarousel-->
            </div>
            <!--/well-->
        </div>
    </div>


    <script language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 10000
            })

            $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
                //alert("slid");
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I copied it directly from the site so i'm not sure why its happening.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below you have difference in image linking in first row you have used img src as given below 500x500

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
```

and in second row you have used img src as given below 250x250

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
```

Here both has different width and height of image keep single source image of same height so that i could not make difference in each slide.

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
</div>
<!--/item-->
<div class="item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
</div>
```

Comment: Geez should have paid attention more.  Thanks